# Can I use context/store values outside of svelte pages?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, vite, sveltekit, postcss

I am working on a Svelte project where I fetch color values from a backend service in a `+page.svelte` file. I have a `customtheme.ts` file where I have logic to enrich one color into 9 shades to get all the Tailwind color shades.

I am trying to use these fetched colors to dynamically change the default colors in `customtheme.ts` and then export them to the Tailwind config file. However, I am unable to retrieve these values using either 'context' or 'store'. Every time I try this, I get the following error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Function called outside component initialization
```

I have tried using setContext and onMount in the +page.svelte file to change the default colors in customtheme.ts, but the component did not mount due to the error mentioned above.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully use the fetched colors to dynamically change the Tailwind CSS colors?

Comment: Doesn't all the Tailwind stuff happen at build time, how can you update that? What is the code you tried to use?